# How to place a toolbar in the middle and on top of appbar (vue, vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Need to place toolbar on top of the appbbar in the middle

[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDV2n.png)

[how to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psi5H.png)

The toolbar is in the appbar tag. And I need the toolbar to be in the center and above the appbar as in the picture. How to do it?

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar app color="primary" dark prominent>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

      <v-toolbar-title>ГринКэп</v-toolbar-title>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <div>
        <v-toolbar>
          <v-toolbar-items>
            <v-btn v-for="link in links" :key="link.title" :to="link.url" text>
              <v-icon left>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
              {{ link.title }}
            </v-btn>
          </v-toolbar-items>
        </v-toolbar>
      </div>
    </v-app-bar>
```

Comment: I tried adding a "absolute" property for toolbar, but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar app color="primary" dark prominent style="position: relative;">
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

      <v-toolbar-title>ГринКэп</v-toolbar-title>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <div>
        <v-toolbar absolute style="top: 65%;left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)">
          <v-toolbar-items>
            <v-btn v-for="link in links" :key="link.title" :to="link.url" text>
              <v-icon left>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
              {{ link.title }}
            </v-btn>
          </v-toolbar-items>
        </v-toolbar>
      </div>
    </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

I have added `top` and `left` to the toolbar, you can remove `position: relative` on app bar if you want.

Comment: Thanks friend, it works)
It is a pity that I can not put a plus to the useful your answer, but it works!